# Does uniqueness: true on my model duplicate unique: true in a db index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to debug an error I'm getting from Sentry:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_authors_on_fb_username"
DETAIL:  Key (fb_username)=(fakeUser) already exists.
```

I recently added `uniqueness: true` to the following validation in my model file `validates :medium_username, presence: true`.

I just realized that before that, I already had `add_index :authors, :fb_username, unique: true` from an old validation that I'd created.

FWIW, I create the author this way

`author = Author.find_or_create_by(fb_id: json["userId"])`

then set some attributes of the author and then get the error occasionally when I call `author.save`. I can't seem to recreate locally.

Is the model validation necessary? Is it a duplicate? Is the db validation enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is the model validation necessary? Is it a duplicate? Is the db validation enough?

**Yes. No. No.**

You need both if uniqueness is actually important.

Model validations simply catch most uniqueness violations before they happen and provide the user with feedback. They do not actually guarantee that your database table will not contain rows with duplicate values since they are [prone to race conditions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

[image: Diagram of a race condition. Image courtesy of Thoughtbot.]

This isn't even actually a rare condition. Any double-clicking senior citizen can potentially create a race condition unless you have a throttle in place.

A unique index guarantees on the database level that two duplicate values cannot be inserted into the table as the DB will reject any insert (or update) that violates the constraint. This is vital if uniqueness is actually important. But when you try to insert a value and it violates a unique constrain a database driver error is raised which will potentially crash your application, which is not want you typically would want.

Comment: Thanks Max, this is really helpful. So then if I have both the model validation and the index validation like I did before, how can I avoid this duplicate key error I've been getting?

Comment: That's impossible to answer with the information given. You really need to isolate it and create minimal reproducable example if you want detailed debugging advise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Fair, thanks Max. I'll put together more info